# Gradle/Spring Boot packages are not found in working build

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, visual-studio-code

I have the problem that my working spring boot project is not working on linux/mac's VS-Code.

On Windows everything is working fine, whenever I clone and try to work on mac or ubuntu (vs code) I have the problem that, even tough the build runs fine, vs code is generating me a lot of errors due missing packages/failed imports.

Example:

```
package org.springframework.boot does not exist
...(Many more failed imports)..
```

My build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.7'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'de.hsrm.mi.web'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

So far I have tried:

- Hours of googling
- Clean Java Language Workspace
- Update Project
- ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
- Initializing a brand new project

No matter what I am trying, I can not get rid of the import errors.
The build just runs fine and without any errors.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have also created a Build Scan and gradle just detects the dependencies without any trouble

Comment: So basically it works... It is only VSCode that is barking. Did you actually install the gradle stuff for VSCode so it knows how/where to resolve the dependencies... Trying to fix the gradle side won't help (that already works), the problem is your IDE/editor.

Answer (score 0):

I could not really get behind the problem. I got the problem solved by not importing my old (vscode) settings and reinstalling vscode from scratch and adding all the plugins needed for the project manually.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).